# XPath: count number of records in large XML file

Tags: xml, xpath

Can anyone help me with a Xpath command that i can use in XML explorer to count the total number of records? In this case the number of "pandcertificaten".

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an6zY.jpg)

Comment: Share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of count in Xpath expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799263/use-of-count-in-xpath-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The `count` function returns the number of nodes in the node set it receives as its argument.  You should be able to use that pretty directly:

```
count(//pandcertificaten)
```

That will return the number of all `<pandcertificaten>` elements anywhere in the document.  There's actually a similar example on [the main page of XML Explorer's website](https://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/).