# XPath count svg elements in /div

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, screen-scraping

Cant get a list of specific SVG elements in div

With For cycle all is perfect, but XPath count is strange for me.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

race_link = 'https://www.racingtv.com/racecards/bath/244519-visit-four-from-the-top-at-valuerater-co-uk-apprentice-handicap-5?'

race_page = requests.get(race_link)
act_race = html.fromstring(race_page.content)

name_horses = act_race.xpath('//div[@class="racecard__runner__column racecard__runner__name"]/a/text()')
star_horses = act_race.xpath('//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]')

print('--------------------')

for(hrs,star) in zip(name_horses,star_horses):
    st = star.xpath('count(svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])')
    print ('name: {0:<30}stars: {1:<5}'.format(hrs,st))

print(name_horses)
print('--------------------')
print(star_horses)
# stars_list = act_race.xpath('//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]/count(svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])')
# print('stars_list',stars_list)
```

in the last 2 commented line want to made 1 list (stars_list), but always got error message "Invalid Expression".
This drives me crazy, help me guys!
Thanks a lot

Comment: I think `count()` has to be used as external element - full path has to be inside `count()` - `act_race.xpath('count(//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]/svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])')` . Or it can be used inside path only in `[ ]` to compare with value.

Comment: Nope.. if i use external count, all of filled stars is counted, (20.0) instead list with number of stars on each horse :(

Comment: btw.. the full error message (Traceback):

File "c:\_Prog\_PyProg\rcnguk\svg_test_0915.py", line 22, in <module>
    stars_list = act_race.xpath('//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]/count(svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])')
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1581, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: I found information that in XPath 1.0 `count()` can't be used inside `xpath` to get many values. It can be used only as external function to get single value. I don't know if lxml use XPath 1.0 or 2.0 but it can be problem which you can't resolve this way.

Comment: link to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802040/1832058) with information `"This expression is only legal in XPath 2.0."`

Comment: in comment you can't format text so error message and code alway append to question - it will be more readable.

Comment: strange.. within for loop used inside xpath, but xpath got a div element for input

Comment: no, in `for`-loop you also use it as external function for path used in `xpath()`

Comment: in `lxml` documentation is that it support only XPath 1.0 - https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: Yes at this moment i read it.. 
Seems must keep the ugly "for"  loop to counts  :(
Thanks for Your time, and help

Answer (score 0):

Given list comprehension in Python, I think you could rewrite the pure but XPath 2.0 attempt

```
stars_list = act_race.xpath('//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]/count(svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])')
```

to using XPath 1 twice in a list comprehension:

```
stars_list = [div.xpath('count(svg[@class="svg svg-star_filled  svg--on"])') for div in act_race.xpath('//div[@class="timeform__stars timeform__rating--alone"]')]
```

That should give a list of the count of `svg` elements of each `div`.

Comment: So elegant, and more Pythonic, than my ugly code 
Thank You
Best regards
Atirra